# Angular detect Idle user

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to detect idle user (such as no mouse or touch events) and display a pop up warning. I have one service of detecting timeout and another to display the pop up. Time out service is being called from app.run. I have almost completed it, have the following two issues,

1. pop up is being displayed in same page, not as a modal.
2. pop up is being displayed multiple time.

Here is my code.
/*** App ****/

```
var myapp = angular.module("myapp", ['ui.bootstrap']);
myapp.run(function ($rootScope, timeoutService) {    
timeoutService.setup();
});
```

/**** time out sevice ****/

```
  myapp.factory('timeoutService', function ($window, modalService) {
  var timeoutID;
  var startTimer = function () {
    // wait 2 seconds before calling goInactive
    timeoutID = $window.setTimeout(goInactive, 2000);
}
 var resetTimer =function(e) {
    $window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    goActive();
 }
 var goInactive = function () {
     modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then(function (result) {
         alert("Hello");
     });

 }
 var goActive=function() {
     startTimer();
 }
 var modalOptions = {
     closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
     actionButtonText: 'Delete Customer',
     headerText: 'Delete ?',
     bodyText: 'Are you sure you want to delete this customer?'
 };
var timeOutService = {};
timeOutService.setup = function () {
    $window.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
    $window.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
    $window.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
    $window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", resetTimer, false);
    $window.addEventListener("mousewheel", resetTimer, false);
    $window.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
    $window.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", resetTimer, false);
    startTimer();
};    
return timeOutService;
});
```

/****** Modal Service ******/

```
 myapp.service('modalService', ['$modal', function ($modal) {

var modalDefaults = {
    backdrop: true,
    keyboard: true,
    modalFade: true,
    templateUrl:'../Modal.html'
};
var modalOptions = {
    closeButtonText: 'Close',
    actionButtonText: 'OK,',
    headerText: 'Proceed?',
    bodyText: 'Perform this action?'
};
this.showModal = function (customModalDefaults, customModalOptions) {
    if (!customModalDefaults) customModalDefaults = {};
    customModalDefaults.backdrop = 'static';
    return this.show(customModalDefaults, customModalOptions);
};
this.show = function (customModalDefaults, customModalOptions) {
    //Create temp objects to work with since we're in a singleton service
    var tempModalDefaults = {};
    var tempModalOptions = {};

    //Map angular-ui modal custom defaults to modal defaults defined in service
    angular.extend(tempModalDefaults, modalDefaults, customModalDefaults);

    //Map modal.html $scope custom properties to defaults defined in service
    angular.extend(tempModalOptions, modalOptions, customModalOptions);

    if (!tempModalDefaults.controller) {
        tempModalDefaults.controller = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
            $scope.modalOptions = tempModalOptions;
            $scope.modalOptions.ok = function (result) {
                $modalInstance.close(result);
            };
            $scope.modalOptions.close = function (result) {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        }
    }

    return $modal.open(tempModalDefaults).result;
};

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create a global controller that functions defined beginning , this driver can be used on the homepage or send calls from any page of the document .
Reference should be made to assign the controller html < div ng - controller = " SesionCtrl "> < / div >

```
app.controller('SesionCtrl',function($scope,Idle,Keepalive,$log){
 $Scope.$On('IdleStart',function(){
 //Open Modal code
 });
 $ Scope . $ On ( ' IdleTimeout ', function () {
  // The end of the timeout Logout
  window.location = " logout.php " ;
 });
} ) ;

<html lang="en"ng-app="myApp">
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="SesionCtrl"></div><!--Instance Controller-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation of your answer to help other users of the site.